# How to implement a ProgressDialog as follows: Start, Finish checking, Close dialog then open new Activity?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm using my phone, so no code I can copy for now.

But I'm making a LoginScreen which leads to HomeScreen if the user exists.
I want a Spinner ProgressDialog shows once I click LoginButton, then the dialog remains active till checking is finished, and go to HomeScreen if user found, and remain at the same LoginScreen if failed.
Please just refer to the logic of logging in by "//LoginLogic", I only want to know how to correctly implement the ProgressDialog and where to put the logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog; //Global
```

onCreate initialize

```
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

before your onClickListener

```
 mProgressDialog.setTitle("Your Title");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Your Message");
                mProgressDialog.show();
                mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true/false);
```

once your authentication is finished place the code where ever required

```
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

best-case if your are using onCompleteListener,

```
if(task.isSuccessful) {
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out, it helped me to figure out the way it works, before I was lost for some reason